# SQL recursive parameters in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get data that uses concatenated value from 3 columns as parameter on my WHERE clause. Is this possible?

```
SELECT [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity FROM b WHERE
PrimaryKey in (select concat_value from b)
```

OR

```
SELECT [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity FROM b WHERE
PrimaryKey = CONCAT(tmp_date,Plant,FamilyName)
```

I used the second one, but no results. But when I try

```
select [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity from b where PrimaryKey = '2018-04-16CMKKB113'
```

I get the desired output. 
I just need to apply it to all rows.

What I want to accomplish is to calculate **Total Backlog QTY** column.
The formula would be **Total Backlog QTY (of the previous day)** - **Daily_Capacity**.
So for **NewDate 17/04/2018**, the value of **Total Backlog QTY** would be **375654**.   (381,654 - 600)

And so on..

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: Try adding more detail to the Question like sample input and your expected output. That may help others to solve the problem more quickly

Comment: 2nd one will work for you. Please try it.

Comment: I used the second one, but no results.

But when I try 

select [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity from b where PrimaryKey = '2018-04-16CMKKB113' 

I get the desired output. I just need to apply it to all rows.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: What does the `PrimaryKey` look like? Is it a single column with all these values concatenated or multiple columns?

Comment: single column that comes from 3 concatenated columns

Comment: @Franz, tmp_date column is `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype?

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: Please don't post sample data as an image. That doesn't help at all. post it as DDL + DML so that we could copy and paste it to a test environment.

Comment: @Franz, Try my updated answer.

Comment: The tmp_date and your primary don't fit, that's why you won't get any results with concat!!! You need the *NewDate*!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity FROM b WHERE
PrimaryKey = CONCAT(tmp_date,Plant,FamilyName)
```

will work definitly .

`CONCAT` function combines three values into one values .

May be your primarykey column does not have that values

Comment: First print CONCAT method value where it is printing the desired result like you have harcoded . May be then you could find what is wrong going on here

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data:

PrimaryKey comes from the concatenation of NewDate, Plant, and FamilyName.

SELECT [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity FROM b WHERE
PrimaryKey = CONCAT(CONVERT(date, NewDate, 120), Plant,FamilyName)

syntax: CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)
for the style you can use 120 see this link for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: @Franz please try this, hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If your tmp_date is not a valid `DATE` datatype, then `CONVERT` it into `DATE` and try the following.

Try this:

```
SELECT [Less Total Backlog QTY] - Daily_Capacity 
FROM b 
WHERE PrimaryKey = CONCAT(CONVERT(date, tmp_date, 105),Plant,FamilyName)
```

**Change VARCHAR to DATE Format:**

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(tmp_date DATETIME,Plant VARCHAR(10),FamilyName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES ('16-04-2018','CMKK','B113')

SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(date, tmp_date, 105),Plant,FamilyName)Concat_date_Value 
FROM @tab
```

***OutPut***:

```
Concat_date_Value
2018-04-16CMKKB113
```

Comment: @Franz, Give some problematic sample data for, `PrimaryKey` and all other 3 columns.

Comment: @Franz, Try my Updated answer. Hope it helps you.